# Front room is 5 degrees hotter in summer and 5 degrees colder in winter. Need to know the root issue and possible solutions?

Tags: hvac, temperature

I have a Front room that is always 5 degrees hotter in summer and 5 degrees colder in winter.

I have had some people suggest it is the Sun on the front room causing the issue; however I have an issue with that because the same sun that shines on the front of the house in the summer is the same sun that shines on the front of the house in the winter.

The home is in Florida, USA.

I would like to know the root issue and possible solutions ?

Some thoughts I have had is that the distribution baffle from the air handler to the rooms is not properly configured. I believe the actual air tube is properly sized.

Is there a way I can know for sure about the proper baffling without too much trouble ?
Is there a calculation of airflow for a particular room size that I should have?

Comment: It might be the same sun, but it's not at the same angle, so there's less 'power' from it as it penetrates more atmosphere in winter. This difference decreases the closer you get to the equator. Florida looks to be about the same distance from the tropics as Tenerife, somewhere I do know, & even there the difference is noticeable from summer to winter. Wall thickness, material & whether you are part of a block or have a roof directly above the room will also make a deal of difference.

Comment: The front foyer is in basically the same location as the front room right next to it,it is not warmer there in the summer or colder in the winter. The garage in front has no insulation and no heating or ac; it does get warmer in the summer and cooler in the winter, that is because it is not insulated nor temperature controlled,. If I added the temp control to it; I suspect it would be fine even though it faces the same sun and has a metal door with no insulation. I think it is 10 to 15 degrees variance in summer/winter you gave me an idea to measure it for comparison though.

Comment: What would you say is the window area to wall area in that room(just for outside facing walls)?   Temperature control depends on many factors, air flow control, insulation, location in a house, and amount of sun hitting the walls and windows.

Comment: try an Anemometer

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, this is such a common problem in Florida. I had a similar situation where my living room, largest room, was hotter than the rest of the house. Equal sided L shaped room with two registers in the short sides of the L. I put an "extension cord" on my thermostat and moved it around different areas to see if I could balance the temperature but no luck but interesting how it changed. Checked the attic and found that the two ducts that fed the living room also fed the kitchen and a bedroom. Long story short (I know, already a long story) I ended up adding a 5" duct straight into the plenum and added an additional register to the lower corner of the L  and this corrected everything. I've duplicated this solution in quite a few homes in the subdivision.

You'll need to get in your attic and check the duct work to see how it's routed and the sizes.

Comment: Yes - I had expanded the 4 inch duct to a 6 inch duct thinking that would help. 
I am really thinking the distribution box was not properly configured and I might transfer one of the other ducts to that room as a test - just not sure how to do that since I have one main that goes down the center to feed living room , master and kitchen.  I think I need to peek inside .. I will unfortunately need to wait for a good storm to cool things off or the winter ..

Comment: Just curious at what side of the L is your return air duct (RAD). Mine is up front by this room area and so the large registers for living area are away from the RAD, 
Normally rooms closest to RAD are cooler ..

Comment: @Ken  My RAD is in a hallway down from the outside lower point of the L where the two walls meet.  I always felt the other rooms got better air flow. Adding the duct to the plenum reduced some of the air to all the other rooms instead of just to some if I had connected it to another duct run.  Instead of robbing Peter to save Paul, I robbed everyone to save Paul.  Yes!! wait for a cooler day to go up into your attic, it's brutal this time of year.

Comment: Where are the return ducts? I have mine setup with two registers for each return, one on the ceiling and the other at the floor. Top open for summer, bottom open for winter. Make a big difference and for me it simply required to cut a hole and add a register.

Comment: @Gil My return has two registers: one large one in the hallway and a smaller one in the bedroom so I get good Air flow when the door's closed. both are high on the wall. Ii put in a whole house fan for the winter months, can't get used to turning on the heat down here.....  from Chicago

Comment: I do not have an L - I have basically a squarish house - it is Florida. As viewed from street front RtL room  , entry, garage. I am thinking the ducting in the distribution is not correct - as I just installed new smoke detectors with multisensors for Temp, Humidity and VOC. The front mini hall ceiling between frontroom and middle room temp is about 4 degrees warmer than the the unit on ceiling in living space. I am thinking this fall to go attic climbing and disconnect the larger air duct and have a look to see if anything is baffled. I suspect bad AC installation company.